# How to kill a process by its full name, including the path?

Tags: process, kill, kill-process

Given the full file name of a process, how can I kill it? Not only by its file name, but by **full file name**. I've looked into kill and pkill and they're not what I'm looking for.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I used pkill and it works, pkill -9 /usr/sbin/td-agent

Answer (score 2):

If your script can be shown by its full name including the path using *ps*, you can easily do that:

```
MYPID=$( ps faux | grep '/tmp/test.sh' | grep -vw grep | awk '{ print $2 }' );
echo ${MYPID};
kill -9 ${MYPID};
```

Note: I run it on Debian Jessie, so if you do so or use a Debian-based distro, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux with lsof you could do this and pipe the output to `kill`.
I use `lsof` to search for processes holding the executable, and then check whether the executable of that process points to the file of interest.

```
NAME=/my/object/that/executes
CANON=`readlink -en "$NAME"`
[ -n "$CANON" ] || exit 1
for pid in `lsof -tf -- "$CANON"`
do
 PIDEXE=`readlink -en /proc/$pid/exe`
 [ x"$CANON" == x"$PIDEXE" ] && echo $pid
done
```

Limitations:

This requires the executable to be still visible in the file system and you will not find processes that started with this executable in a different location or that only used the executable for bootstrapping.

And **beware**, this sort of thing is very sensitive to race conditions, you might end up killing *innocent* processes.